# Input value not showing up (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got this controller:

```
app.controller('controlFormulario', function($scope) {
  this.formulario = [];
  this.formulario.fecha = new Date();
});
```

...this directive:

```
app.directive('formulario', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // C: class, E: element, M: comments, A: attributes
    templateUrl: 'modules/formulario.html'

  };
```

... and this view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
  <input type="fecha" class="form-control" id="fecha" ng-model="fecha" value="{{formCtrl.formulario.fecha | date}}"  disabled>
</div>
```

As you may guess, the attribute value has the date, perfectly filtered and so. No problem here. The actual problem comes when you see the website, and find out that the input doesn't show up anything. The "value" attribute is perfectly assigned, but it's not showing it inside the input box.

Why? Am I doing something wrong? Tried the same with ng-init, ng-value... I'm a newbye on AngularJS, just ended the basic tutorial and I'm trying to practise and get some more knowledge, so maybe I'm missing out something.

Any help?

Comment: Why are you not using $scope?

Comment: Frankly, I began seeing the $scope thingy when I ended the tutorial, in the actual uses of Angular. I've got no idea on what it's used for, since Google didn't do any mention to it in the basic tutorial... I think it's not a need though, since the logic of the problem works: the value is saved in, it just doesn't appear, like if it's an HTML5 problem or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the data attribute to the $scope.

Check out this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: Why must I use $scope? I still don't understand why, since the data logic works fine defining the controller in the form as <form ng-controller="controlFormulario as formCtrl">... is it any good to use?

Comment: It worked, but I still find this pretty clunky. What's the difference between setting the controller form object (this.formulario) and setting the $scope? If I use an expression that accesses to this object's variable (this.formulario.fecha), it appears in the DOM, but not on the visible page, while if I set it as a ng-model with the same name than the scope, it appears perfectly.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, you shouldn't use `$scope`, instead, like you did, you should use `controllerAs`, so, in your controller:

```
var cf = this;
```

and then, instead of using

```
this.formulario = []; 
this.formulario.fecha = new Date();
```

you should have

```
cf.formulario = [];
cf.fetcha = new Date();
```

then, in your html, you would have

```
ng-controller="controlFormulario as cf"
```

Then, the input `model` becomes: `cf.fetcha` and all other scopes from the controller should now be prefixed with `cf.`

```
<input type="fecha" class="form-control" id="fecha" ng-model="cf.fecha" value="{{formCtrl.formulario.fecha | date}}"  disabled>
```

> Here is a good [Article](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) that better explains this